# React cannot get array informations

Tags: reactjs, arrays

Hello I am making a chess game and I wanted to get information in console about every squares.ver and my problem is that I cannot get squares.ver from squares in switch case in console its written "test not passed" so its doing default switch and none of other cases. I don't know what the problem is.

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";

const horizontalLine = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
const squares = verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
  horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
    {
      id: `${verticals+horizontals}`,
      ver: `${verticals}`,
      hor: `${horizontals}`
    }
  ))
));




function App() {
  switch(squares){
    case squares.ver = "a":
      console.log("a")
      break
    case squares.ver = "b":
      console.log("b")
      break
    case squares.ver = "c":
      console.log("c")
      break
    case squares.ver = "d":
      console.log("d")
      break
    case squares.ver = "e":
      console.log("e")
      break
    case squares.ver = "f":
      console.log("f")
      break
    case squares.ver = "g":
      console.log("g")
      break
    case squares.ver = "h":
      console.log("h")
      break
    default:
      console.log("test not passed")
      break
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {squares.map((square) => (
        square.map((innerSquare) =>
         <div className='square' id={innerSquare.id} key={innerSquare.id} ver={innerSquare.ver} hor={innerSquare.hor}>{innerSquare.id}</div>
      )))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `squares` is an array, so `switch(squares)` doesn't really make sense and `squares.ver` is always going to be undefined. Is there a specific element of the array that you want to log out? Or do you want to log them all out?

Answer (score 1):

You used the `switch case` wrong, and `squares` has no elements such as `ver`. That is because `squares` is actually an array that has multiple arrays as elements due to your nested `map` array functions. This makes it not possible to use a `switch case` unless you `map` through the array or use a specific index.
Check [MDN switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

This is the code for a specific index:

```
 switch(squares[0][0].ver){
    case "a":
      console.log("a")
      break
    case "b":
      console.log("b")
      break
    case "c":
      console.log("c")
      break
    case "d":
      console.log("d")
      break
    case "e":
      console.log("e")
      break
    case "f":
      console.log("f")
      break
    case "g":
      console.log("g")
      break
    case "h":
      console.log("h")
      break
    default:
      console.log("test not passed")
      break
  }
```